# javascript username password https login issue for windows phone 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am a newbie coming from IOS and Android and trying to replicate a feature in those apps where I use a username and password that is saved in preferences (isolatedstorage) and inject it into the javascript of the https web page.  From a [previous question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308499/cant-add-system-windows-froms-without-could-not-be-resolved-error) before I now understand that I can not use System.Windows.Forms as that is for W8Desktop and I am targeting windows phone 8.

In android I did the following:

```
view.loadUrl(“javascript:document.getElementById(‘Login1_UserName’).value=’”+userName+”‘;javascript:document.getElementById(‘Login1_Password’).value = ‘”+password+”‘;”);
view.loadUrl(“javascript:document.getElementById(‘Login1_LoginButton’).click();”);
```

and I am trying to do it in Visual Studio 2012 but its not working. Here is my code:

```
Browser.Navigate(new Uri(mainUrl, UriKind.Absolute));

Browser.InvokeScript(“eval”, new string[] { “document.getElementById(‘Login1_UserName’).value = ‘”+username+”‘ , document.getElementById(‘Login1_Password’).value = ‘”+password+”‘;”});
Browser.InvokeScript(“eval”, new string[] { “document.getElementById(‘Login1_LoginButton’).click();”});
```

But it just wont work. So my questions are two:

1. If I want to create a small script I assume that is called eval,  do I add a resource file to my project or add it as a block of code in my mainpage.xaml.cs?  If so how?
2. If I do as above, is there an issue with my syntax?

Many thanks for any pointers you may be able to give to help.

Comment: Hi Guys, still need to solve this incase someone drops pass this question and has some idea as to what I am doing incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a solution now, but still need to know how to implement it.

Here is the correct code to inject javascript into the form.

```
 browser.InvokeScript("eval", "document.getElementById('Login1_UserName').value = '" + username + "';");
 browser.InvokeScript("eval", ("document.getElementById('Login1_Password').value = '" + password + "';"));
 browser.InvokeScript("eval", string.Format("document.getElementById('Login1_LoginButton').click();"));
```

The issue I had was that I was not allowing the page to finish loading before running the script.  I have tried a few things but to no aval so I will keep digging and edit once I have it solved.

Hope this helps someone else.

JUST REMEMBER YOU CAN NOT USE browser.document as you see in some solutions as it wont work on windows phone.  Happy to be corrected as I am a newbie, but that trail cost me too many hours.  You need to use Invokescript for windows phone code.

Comment: Ok, I have checked out every possible method for the webbrowser and every time I try and load the page and then wait for it to load before injecting the javascript, I get an error.  So after talking with the server chap, we are modifying it and doing a POST with username and password instead.  But if you just need to inject javascript on an already loaded page, then this will definitely work.